# Python Tkinter label widget doesn't update

Tags: python, tkinter

Here's a piece of simplified code which doesn't work as i want it to:

```
def get_tl(self,x):

    self.var_tl = IntVar()

    if x == "Random (max = 6)":
        self.var_tl.set(randint(1,6))        

    else:

        ask_tl = Toplevel()
        def destroy_t_set_tl():
            self.var_tl.set(entry_tl_t.get())
            ask_tl.destroy()

        label_tl_t = Label(ask_tl, text="length:").pack(side=LEFT)
        entry_tl_t = Entry(ask_tl, width=25)
        entry_tl_t.pack(side=LEFT)
        button_enter_tl_t = Button(ask_tl, text="Enter", command=destroy_t_set_tl).pack(side=LEFT)

    self.label_tl = Label(self, text="length:").grid(row=1,column=0)

    # This only shows the right number when "Random (max = 6)". When "Manual" it shows 0
    self.show_tl = Label(self, text=self.var_tl.get()).grid(row=1,column=1)

def get_values(self):

    # This always shows the right number.
    self.total_label = Label(self, text=self.var_tl.get()).grid(row=4,column=0)
```

The function `get_tl` is called by an OptionMenu widget which gives x the values: `"Manual"` or `"Random (max = 6)"`.

When this function is called I want it to choose a random number or open a Toplevel window which ask the user a number through an Entry. After the random number is chosen or the user has given a number. The number needs to be displayed as a label so the user can see if the number is correct.
The label only show the right number when `"Random (max = 6)"`. When `"Manual"` it shows 0

After a button is pressed the function `get_values` is called. This however **does** give the right number regardless if it is manual or random.

I'm probably making a simple mistake here. But I fail to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the answer to my own question:

```
def get_tl(self,x):

    def tl():
        self.label_tl = Label(self, text="length:").grid(row=1,column=0)
        self.show_tl = Label(self, text=self.var_tl.get()).grid(row=1,column=1)

    if x == "Random (max = 6)":
        self.var_tl.set(randint(1,6))
        tl()
    else: 


        ask_tl = Toplevel()
        def destroy_t_set_tl():
            self.var_tl.set(entry_tl_t.get())
            ask_tl.destroy()
            tl()

        label_tl_t = Label(ask_tl, text="length:").pack(side=LEFT)
        entry_tl_t = Entry(ask_tl, width=25)
        entry_tl_t.pack(side=LEFT)
        button_enter_tl_t = Button(ask_tl, text="Enter", command=destroy_t_set_tl).pack(side=LEFT)



def get_values(self):

    self.total_label = Label(self, text=self.var_tl.get()).grid(row=4,column=0)
```

Now both the option `"Manual"` and `"Random"` will call the function `tl()` which will show the number so the user can check it.
I also moved the `self.var_tl = IntVar()` to the constructor of the class. It might not be the optimal solution but for me it works.

Answer (score 0):

In this part:

```
def get_tl(self,x):

    self.var_tl = IntVar()
```

You're recreating the variable over and over again, so it holds the default value of `0`, as explained in [the documentation](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/Tkinter.IntVar-class.html):

> VALUE is an optional value (defaults to 0)

Then you set the variable **only** if `x == "Random (max = 6)"`, so in all other cases it will remain at its default.

Possibly you want to remove this line:

```
self.var_tl = IntVar()
```

You should have it only in the constructor of your class. Then all your methods will share the same instance pointed by `self.var_tl`.